# Allow a specific user to sudo to users that are part of group X

Tags: sudo, group

I have several users, which are all part of group X.

And I want to be able to give user Y to sudo to members of group X.

Obviously I don't want to edit sudoers everytime I add a user to group X, is there an elegant way to solve this? sudoers doesn't seem to have syntax for this.

Answer (score 2):

Wherever you can write a user name (`User` list or `Runas` list), you can write `%` followed by a group name instead.

```
Y ALL = (%X) ALL
```